# Компиляция в exe файл

Tags: компиляция, exe

пытаюсь скомпилировать файл .py, созданный в VS, в exe-файл, но никак не получается.
При попытке вызова auto-py-to-exe, или pyinstaller, пишет:

"auto-py-to-exe" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Прошу помочь с этой проблемой.

Comment: Я просто оставлю это здесь )))\
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67851955/how-to-fix-auto-py-to-exe-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command